# PDO results are empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I decided to flip from mysqli/mysqlnd to PDO, however I am encountering a problem I had the last time I did this. I am trying this again as it seems that PDO allegedly supports passing a variable that contains an array of values to the `execute()` param for binding to the query without having to use things like `call_user_func_array`.

The code I have for demonstration is :

```
$bind_arguments[] = "dogs";
$bind_arguments[] = "cats";
$bind_arguments[] = "birds";

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . SQL_DATA . ';host=' . SQL_SERVER, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD, array (
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
)); 

$sql = 'SELECT `name` FROM `pets` WHERE `type` = ? OR `type` = ? OR `type` = ?';

$result = Array();
try {

    if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {

        $stmt->execute($bind_arguments);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();


    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); exit;
}

$db = null;

var_export($result);  // null
```

I don't get any exceptions, however `$result` is null.  If I do the regular query using Navicat (or using `mysqli`) It works!

See [Example #5](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), which shows I should be able to do this (posting example from there here for reference) :

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement using an array of values for an IN clause */
$params = array(1, 21, 63, 171);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

/*
    This prepares the statement with enough unnamed placeholders for every value
    in our $params array. The values of the $params array are then bound to the
    placeholders in the prepared statement when the statement is executed.
    This is not the same thing as using PDOStatement::bindParam() since this
    requires a reference to the variable. PDOStatement::execute() only binds
    by value instead.
*/
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE id IN ($place_holders)");
$sth->execute($params);
?>
```

Also see [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) posted below for convenience :

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

So why is this not working ? What am I doing wrong ?

**Update**

I made some typos when posting my code (which was stripped out of a larger class) for [StackOverflow's MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements. These typos were not present in the original class.  I have updated them in the code above.  - sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: In the first code snippet that you posted, you used `$db = new PDO...` but in the try/catch block you're using `$this->_db->prepare`. Is that your real code or? Also, why would you use `$db = null`? That will completely annihilate any speck of performance since in FCGI apps you want to have persistent connections in order to avoid tcp handshake and credential checking on every request.

Comment: @Mjh - good eye, sorry, I harvested it out from a class for [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In the actual project `$this->_db` is the object.  Updating sample above

Comment: at some point I had a similar phenomenon and started using bindValue to set the values and called execute without params. ;o(

Comment: Looks like your problem is error reporting. null means error, but you don't get any. What is your error reporting level?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - all errors are logged to apache log with full stack trace.

Comment: Your code works here - exactly as you have it. Surprise you used plural as your column 'type'. Whatever - it works fine without any changes.

Comment: @RyanVincent - it turns out, I was looking for results from a query that didn't return any results.  How this happened -- a lot is going on, and when I switched on debug to see what was happening (var_export() + exit;), it was terminating after a query that was being processed before the one i was actively inspecting XD.   Tip:  This is a good reason why humans need sleep  lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning values to `$bind_array` and `$bnid_array` but are sending in `$bind_arguments` to `execute()`. Try changing `$bnid_array` to `$bind_array` and use `$stmt->execute($bind_array);`

Comment: just a typo when stripping down for [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) correcting now.  problem is not relevant to that.

Comment: Also, if that was the problem, it would have produced a PDOException when attempting to execute a null variable.